# Facebook API search entirely JS

Tags: jquery, facebook-graph-api

```
var url = "http://graph.facebook.com/search?q=" + keyword + "&type=post"; 
$.get(url, function(data) { etc..
```

Trying to pull this directly through javascript and needs to be js.  I keep getting denied.  What is the authentication for an app through JS to take care of this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.get('http://graph.facebook.com/search',{'q':keyword,'type':'post'}, function(data){},'javascript');
```

It might work---
If not,  `$.getScript` ?

Comment: Your code sample isn't functionally different from the OP's question, it's just a refactor. If he's having (what I'm guessing is) [SOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) issues, this won't help at all.

Comment: Hmm, weird. Well I stand corrected, then. I'm still not sure what's different though.

Comment: Well, I set that the result should be javascript, maybe then able for the rest of the script to read the result?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [`FB.api`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/) call:

```
FB.api('/search', {'q': keyword, 'type': 'post'}, function(response)
{
    // handle response
});
```